Generalization (?) of the Jensen's inequality
Is there anyone aware of some possible generalization of the Jensen's inequality to operators with certain properties? For instance, does the following hold true for the standard projection operator $\mathrm{proj}_C:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$:
$$\mathbb{E}[\|\mathrm{proj}_C(X)\|]\ge\|\mathrm{proj}_C(\mathbb{E}[X])\|$$
where $X\in\mathbb R^n$ is some random variable and $C\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ is a closed convex set?

A general form of Jensen's inequality in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ for a convex function $f: \mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}$ and a random integrable variable $X := (X_{1},\dots,X_{n}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is
$$
E(f(X_1,\dots,X_n)) \ge f(E(X_1),\dots,E(X_n)).
$$Instead of $f$ you can take $g := f \circ L$, where $L: \mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is linear, $g$ will stay convex. If $C$ in your example is linear we can take $f = \lVert \cdot \rVert$ and $L = proj_{C}$. You can apply it differently to get some other forms.
If $C$ is not linear, then it doesn't hold even in $\mathbb{R}$, take $C=[0,1]$ and $X$ with two point distribution $\frac 12 \delta_2 + \frac 12 \delta_{0}$.
Basically if the function is not convex it is easy to construct a  conterexample, because Jensen's inequality is just a limit generalization of the convex property.
If you are interested in the generalizations of Jensen's inequality in infinite-dimensional spaces, see real analysis - Generalization of Jensen's inequality to multivariate functions - Mathematics Stack Exchange.

$L=\mathrm{proj}_C(\cdot)$ does not look linear though.
